# Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone created in Route53 and updated the NS records under the namespaces of the purchased domain.

Unfortunately the DNS check does not return or point to the new NS records instead gets resolved to old/ previously existing records.

I waited more than 72 hours and still i get "This site can’t be reached"failing with error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in the browser.

Below is a screenshot from the DNS check provided by https://mxtoolbox.com/,

[image]

It shows that the old NS records (First 4 rows with TTL to 48 hours) are present in the local and not in parent whereas the newly updated records (The last 4 records) are present in the parent and not in the local.

Ping to the domain fails with Unknown host.

What are the next steps?

Comment: Do you have the old and new name servers configured at the same time for your domain? That is not correct. Remove the old name servers and only use the new name servers.

Comment: @JohnHanley I removed the old name space records which was present under the domain and updated with the new one in the Route 53. Can you please suggest when will the old NS records will be removed completely or any way to force remove it when i do a DNS check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you update the name servers for a domain, remove the old name server records.

Your TTL is set to 48 hours. That means any recursive resolver such as [dns.google](https://dns.google/) will not refresh for 48 hours after last update. For resolvers that have not cached your resource records, they might update immediately but might also get stale data from an upstream resolver. Wait a few hours so that you do not force a new cache load with old data and then check with an Internet tool such as [dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org/) Change the selection box from A to NS to see the name server changes.

In general I recommend that it takes 48 to 72 hours for authoritative name server changes to propagate around the world.

Google DNS supports "Flush Cache". Wait an hour or two and then request that Google update their DNS cache. [Flush Cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache)

Cloudflare also supports [Purge Cache](https://1.1.1.1/purge-cache/)

Google and Cloudflare are very popular DNS resolvers.

Also, do not forget to flush your local computer's DNS cache:

- Windows: `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Linux: `sudo service network-manager restart` (ubuntu) or `sudo /etc/init.d/nscd restart`
- macOS: `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` followed by `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`